# How can I make this PHP function more efficient at scale?

Tags: php, performance

I have no idea how to make this more efficient, and am working through coding challenges.  Any hints?

The objective is to return the unique value in an array.

[Test Conditions Which Code Fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zZdq.png)

```
function solution($A) {

    foreach ($A as $key => $value) {

        $searchResults = array_keys($A, $value);

        //print "Total number of $value found in Array is: " . count($searchResults) . "\n";

        $checkNumber = count($searchResults);

        if ($checkNumber == 1) {

            //print "Unique value is: $value\n";
            return $value;

        }

        //print "\n";

    }

}
```

Comment: Its an interesting problem. The hint may be `at scale` as a for loop is linear. How then to reduce the iterations by preprocessing the data in such a way that also isn't too costly at scale.

Comment: your function is supposed to return `$value` when it finds the first occurrence of a value that is not repeated throughout the array?

Comment: What is the type of $value?

Comment: @jibsteroos His function is to find the non repeated value by a means that is most efficient. It doesn't necessarily have to return on first occurence, because thats actually what his code does now.

Comment: Or nvm. I think i already know how to optimize And i dont need to know the type. But let me get to PC...

Comment: @slepic, i've thought of a solution too. The OP's current approach searches the array (via array_keys) for each iteration of the loop. And this is why its likely not efficient. Becomes a matter of a suitable data structure for a 1st loop. And then the 2nd loop weeds out the answer. Not yet sure on the details tho on design/implementation.

Comment: @GetSet, then why don't you just post your solution, so we can all see it, carry on. We can help you with the design and implementation details, I'm sure.

Comment: Ok. I could do that. There would be two loops. The first would go fully thru the array. For this loop a tree structure would be used to count the elements in the array. So A A A counts as 3 for one leaf node of A. And B counts as 1 for one leaf node of B. The second loop then traverses the tree for the leaf node that only has one. .. But im not too certain whether a tree should be used as opposed to a hash map.

Comment: The hash map seems the way to go where the bucket distribution would be purposely wide. That is memory would be the sacrifice to speed this whole operation up, even wasted memory.

Comment: Your tests will end up in timeout errors for pretty much any way you code this with arrays, because PHP uses a lot of memory for arrays. I'd try to use strings instead, or maybe splFixedArray

Comment: @niceass Strings have to rebuilt (behind the scenes). As such you'd still end up with alot more iterations than necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest I can come up with is to first use `array_count_values()` to count the occurrences of each value, then just loop along the result and return the first items that has 1 occurrence.  This also returns false if none are found...

```
function solution($a) {
    $counts = array_count_values($a);
    foreach ( $counts as $value => $count ) {
        if ( $count == 1 )  {
            return $value;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The `array_count_values()` will loop across the whole array once (which has to be done in all cases AFAIK), the `foreach` loop will loop across the result till an item is found.

Edit:
If you are going to use objects as the data, you can easily fix this by serializing the data and then following the same process as above.  Using `unserialize()` to return the data...

```
function solution($a) {
    $ser = array_map("serialize", $a);
    $counts = array_count_values($ser);
    foreach ( $counts as $value => $count ) {
        if ( $count == 1 )  {
            return unserialize($value);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I believe this uses the hash approach. I took a look at the C code of array_count_values() before posting. At most there are 2 loops. And the second loop (your foreach) stops once encountered. Definitely an improvement.

Comment: I didn't know about array_count_values() but its good to know now that such a function exists. Why re-create the wheel.

Comment: @GetSet, the PHP has a lot of features which it's difficult to remember all of them.  After a while though just knowing that something will most likely exist is a good starting point to go off and search the manual for it.

Answer (score 3):

Ok so I had a different solution (one that continualy destroys the input array), seems about 30% faster then OP's. But then I benched the solution of Nigel Ren and that one rules them all.

EDIT: Except Ren's solution has one caveat. It does not work with non scalars because it uses the values as array keys. While OP's and mine solutions do (if we tweak the array_keys call with a strict=true, what surprised me is that with strict=true it becomes somewhat slower???).

```
<?php

function solution(array $A) {

    foreach ($A as $key => $value) {

        $searchResults = array_keys($A, $value, true);

        //print "Total number of $value found in Array is: " . count($searchResults) . "\n";

        $checkNumber = count($searchResults);

        if ($checkNumber == 1) {

            //print "Unique value is: $value\n";
            return $value;

        }

        //print "\n";

    }
    return null;
}

function solutionRen($a) {
    $counts = @array_count_values($a); //disable warning when running over nonscalars
    foreach ( $counts as $value => $count ) {
        if ( $count == 1 )  {
            return $value;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function solutionSlepic(array $A)
{
    while (!empty($A)) {
        $value = \array_shift($A);

        $keys = \array_keys($A, $value, true);

        if (empty($keys)) {
            return $value;
        }

        foreach ($keys as $key) {
            unset($A[$key]);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

$range = \range(1,20000);
$input = \array_merge($range, $range, [1000001]);
$input = \array_merge([1000001], $range, $range);
$input = \array_merge($range, $range);
$input = \array_merge(\array_fill(0, 20000, 1), \array_fill(0, 20000, 2));

$input = [];
for($i=0; $i<20000; ++$i) {
    $input[$i] = $input[20000 + $i] = new \stdClass();
}
$input[] = (object) ['unique' => true];

$start = \microtime(true);
$solutionOP = solution($input);
$timeOP = \microtime(true) - $start;
echo "OP: $solutionOP ({$timeOP})\n";

$start = \microtime(true);
$solutionRen = solutionRen($input);
$timeRen = \microtime(true) - $start;
echo "Ren: $solutionRen ({$timeRen})\n";

$start = \microtime(true);
$solutionSlepic = solutionSlepic($input);
$timeSlepic = \microtime(true) - $start;
echo "slepic: $solutionSlepic ({$timeSlepic})\n";
```

Outputs for the various inputs:

```
// unnique valus is on end
OP: 1000001 (1.7094209194183)
Ren: 1000001 (0.00097393989562988)
slepic: 1000001 (1.1519079208374)

// unique value is the first
OP: 1000001 (0.00011515617370605)
Ren: 1000001 (0.0009620189666748)
slepic: 1000001 (0.00069785118103027)

// unique value not found among 20k distinct values, each twice in the set
OP:  (1.728000164032)
Ren:  (0.00064802169799805)
slepic:  (1.18425989151)

// unque value not found among 2 distinct values, each 20k times in the set
OP:  (6.4909980297089)
Ren:  (0.00011396408081055)
slepic:  (0.0016219615936279)

// 20000 distinct objects, each twice in the array and one unique on end
OP: (4.8111519813538)
stdClass Object
(
    [unique] => 1
)
// Ren's solution is not capable of working with types other then those that can be keys of array, and so it didnt find the solution and instead yells 40k php warning which i have muted.
Ren: (0.013867139816284)
slepic: (2.5294151306152)
stdClass Object
(
    [unique] => 1
)
```

Comment: Nice benchmark test. So it be concluded that array_count_values() already has the efficiency built in for the 1st of needed loops. And the second necessary loop is just a linear search. The OP's solution has the flaw of looping N * N if the unique value is at the end of the array.

Comment: @GetSet Yeah, about so. Btw I have added one more input set, one where no unique value exists but the set contains only 2 distinct values, each 20000 times repeated. Anyway, although I haven't checked it, but i suspect that my solution is the least memory exhaustive if it's worth anything...

Comment: I personally think that it can be inferred that memory use is a non-issue in the solution requirement. Efficiency can be many things true. Speed however can be inferred considering that the OP's solution is N * N. Memory I dont think is relevant. The fastest solution is relevant, as your benchmarks show.

Comment: My up vote was not that you found my answer was fastest, but the fact you took time to show the relative performances of the different methods :)

Comment: I upvoted you @NigelRen but I will do the same with slepic. Took some time and effort to come up with this (the benchmark). Am glad that NigelRen came up with a solution faster though because I would have reinvented the wheel (with any and all bugs that might have contained.)

Comment: @NigelRen yeah i had it already written before i refreshed and saw your answer. So i benchmarked it too and when I saw mine was nowhere near i felt like discarding entirelyl, but then i thought at least it will bring some added value. But you definitely deserve the credits for finding the fastest solution.

Comment: @slepic Once we hear back from OP, we'll know definitely. Glad you didn't (and please dont) discard it entirely, because I personally am still studying your code and it could be forked to an entirely different (even if related) solution for me or someone else. Technically your solution is into linked lists (in a way) which would be good for other things not readily apparent.

Comment: @NigelRen I have also figured your solution will not work with nonscalars because array_count_values puts them in array keys. see my edit.

Comment: Fixed - see new code example (it added 1 line of code and minor changes to 2 others).